# Flutter 3.10.4 Windows build not opening some times

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to intgrate between Flutter and Rust to use flutter az ui and rust as core and it's working, but sometimes after double-cliccking on the .exe file to open it it just open and stuck at background and not showing anything, this is my code:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ffi.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'My First Flutter App'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // counter
  int _counter = 0;

  // increment counter
  Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
    int result = await api.rootskyAdd(left: _counter, right: 2);
    setState(() {
      _counter = result;
      // _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const Text(
                'Tell my about yourself.',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                child: const Text('Increment'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ffi.dart

```
// This file initializes the dynamic library and connects it with the stub
// generated by flutter_rust_bridge_codegen.

import 'dart:ffi';

import 'bridge_generated.dart';
import 'bridge_definitions.dart';
export 'bridge_definitions.dart';

// Re-export the bridge so it is only necessary to import this file.
export 'bridge_generated.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;

const _base = 'native';

// On MacOS, the dynamic library is not bundled with the binary,
// but rather directly **linked** against the binary.
final _dylib = io.Platform.isWindows ? '$_base.dll' : 'lib$_base.so';

final Native api = NativeImpl(io.Platform.isIOS || io.Platform.isMacOS
    ? DynamicLibrary.executable()
    : DynamicLibrary.open(_dylib));
```

the ffi.dart file copied directly from https://github.com/Desdaemon/flutter_rust_bridge_template

flutter doctor result

```
> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2846], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.2)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

it's looklike there was same issue for version 3.10.2 and older and in another Question someone mentioned that for android it's fized on 3.10.3

i did not fild out why this is happening, but when i'm using

```
flutter run --release
```

it's ok but when i'm trying to open the exe file it's randomly stuck at background and after several try even without killing old zombie processes it will open

NOTE: i just want it for native windows targets not anything else

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Developer Mode is enabled on your device as you explore the other provided solutions.

Example for Windows 11: You can directly search for Developer Mode in start search option or open Setting > Privacy & security > For developers > Developer Mode.